# How to create a grid of 14 divs taking up full browser screen width with dividers in between groups using html, css (and maybe bootstrap4)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to create two rows of divs that take up the entire width of the screen (14 total with in each row). All the divs are fixed and equal in size and are 'grouped' by color with dividers in between each color group.

I want to make it so that I can have 'divs' that take up the full width of the screen that are equidistant from each other. Is there a way to do this in bootstrap 4 without setting a fixed width for each divs?

Assume:

1. The divs are all equal in size regardless how wide the users browser screen is. Resizing still maintains the same # of divs per row. (No explicit setting of container width to specific px width. Height is okay, e.g. 200px)
2. Ensures divs of the same color stay in the same group (green, blue, and orange) in the example.
3. Has dividers (black color in example image) to divide the groups.
4. Is scalable to support additions of more divs. (say if I wanted to add 2 more orange divs, I should be able to do so without tweaking percentages, etc. of every other square.
5. No modification or overrides of bootstrap out-of-the-box classes if used as part of a solution, though additional custom classes can be specified.

Not sure if bootstrap 4 or current css standards could be used to help with this.

[image]

My current partial solution now is I create 12 individual divs and float left with margins. Though the problem is, when I resize the screen some divs may go to the first row, leaving gaps below I know I can explicitly divide 100 by 7 (the number of divs in the row) and use that as the percentage width for all the divs, but it just seems hacky and leaves whitespace on the rightmost side of the container. I am not sure how to add the black dividers either.

I am looking for a smarter (maybe more modern?) way of implementing this. Does bootstrap 4 help with this?

My current way of doing this (without black dividers, don't know how to fit those in):
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gvKaLW

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="rect green">1</div>
      <div class="rect green">2</div>
      <div class="rect blue">5</div>
      <div class="rect blue"></div>
      <div class="rect blue"></div>
      <div class="rect orange">11</div>
      <div class="rect orange"></div>
      <div class="rect green">3</div>
      <div class="rect green">4</div>
      <div class="rect blue"></div>
      <div class="rect blue"></div>
      <div class="rect blue"></div>      
      <div class="rect orange"></div>
      <div class="rect orange"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.rect {
  background: green;
  width:12%;
  height:200px;
  float:left;
  margin-right:10px;
  margin-top:5px;
  color:white;
  font-size:3em;
}

.green {
  background:green;
}

.blue {
  background:blue;
}

.orange {
  background:orange;
}
```

Comment: Sooo, something like this https://jsfiddle.net/voogn4h1/6/ ?

Comment: @NoobishPro, close, just lacking black dividers. Not looking to make any modifications to bootstrap core classes, though additional custom classes would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only Bootstrap 4 way I can think of is using 7 `col` auto-layout columns, and then nest the `rect` inside of those. Finally use :after elements for the dividers.

https://www.codeply.com/go/D4l7mCFeMr

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="rect green">1</div>
            <div class="rect green">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="rect green">2</div>
            <div class="rect green">4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="rect blue">5</div>
            <div class="rect blue"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="rect blue"></div>
            <div class="rect blue"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="rect blue"></div>
            <div class="rect blue"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="rect orange"></div>
            <div class="rect orange"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="rect orange"></div>
            <div class="rect orange"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works! Great the dividers don't break up, best solution out of all so far.

Answer (score 0):

stackoverflow.com/questions/26746168/… <- might be related to your question.

So yes, one solution is creating a 14-grid bootstrap instead of a 12 grid one. `calc(100% / 7)` is not a hack, it's valid CSS for modern browsers (CSS3). Scaling is going wrong because margins are a forced whitespace. The way bootstrap works, is putting padding on the wrappers and then adding the elements on the inside, creating the illusion of margin when it's actually padding. The padding belongs to the div's width where margin does not, so padding can be responsive. with `box-sizing: border-box`, that is.

So, just skip the bootstrap part and use custom classes with some custom html, like so;

### HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 customBlocks">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="rect green">1</div>
      </div>

      <div class="block">
        <div class="rect green">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="divider">
        <div class="black"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="block">
        <div class="rect blue">5</div>
      </div>

      <div class="block">
        <div class="rect blue"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="block">
        <div class="rect blue"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="divider">
        <div class="black"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="block">
        <div class="rect orange">11</div>
      </div>

      <div class="block">
        <div class="rect orange"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="block">
        <div class="rect green">3</div>
      </div>

      <div class="block">
        <div class="rect green">4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="divider">
        <div class="black"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="block">
        <div class="rect blue"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="block">
        <div class="rect blue"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="block">
        <div class="rect blue"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="divider">
        <div class="black"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="block">
        <div class="rect orange"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="block">
        <div class="rect orange"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.customBlocks {
  padding: 0;
}

.customBlocks .block {
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  width: calc(96% / 7);
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.customBlocks .divider {
  padding: 10px 0 0 0;
  width: 2%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.customBlocks .divider .black {
  background: black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.orange {
  background: orange;
}

.rect {
  background: green;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  color: white;
  font-size: 3em;
  width: 100%;
}
```

### [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/voogn4h1/13/)